# Use zlib unzip gzip stream

Tags: c, zip, gzip, zlib

I got gzip stream looks like this. 
I googled the header 31, -117, 8 should be a gzip file.

`{31, -117, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -29, 22, 98, -27, 96, 80, 120, -63, -34, -59, -104, -58, -63, 44, -108, 96, 92, 99, 100, 104, 102, 104, 105, 102, 97, 110, 82, -109, -100, -97, -85, -105, -107, -105, -103, -110, -102, -101, -81, -105, 88, 80, 80, -100, -97, 83, 90, -110, -103, -97, 7, 19, -85, 49, -84, 113, -12, -53, -15, -9, 8, -12, 79, 75, 115, 77, 116, -11, 44, 72, 118, 76, -12, -15, 12, 44, -9, 118, -85, 40, -48, 118, 13, -56, -86, 74, -52, 115, 45, -73, -75, -83, 49, 52, 49, 53, 54, 50, 52, 50, 51, 52, 53, 53, 48, -111, 98, -32, 1, 0, -106, 39, -125, -109, 114, 0, 0, 0};`

I think this should be a gzip file right?

Then I use zlib to unzip this file

```
    do {
    do {
        s->strm.avail_in = s->size;
        s->strm.next_in = s->buf;
        s->strm.next_in = (Bytef *)tmp;

        s->strm.avail_out = ZCHUNK;
        s->strm.next_out = s->zbuf;

        ret = inflate(&s->strm, Z_SYNC_FLUSH);
        //    ret = inflateInit2(&s->strm, 16+MAX_WBITS);

        if (ret == Z_STREAM_ERROR) {
            printf("ret error");
        }

        if (ret == Z_MEM_ERROR) {
            printf("ret mem error");
        }

        if (ret == Z_DATA_ERROR) {
            printf("ret data error\n");
        }

        if (ret == Z_NEED_DICT) {
            printf("ret dict error");
        }

        if (ret != 0){
            (void)inflateEnd(&s->strm);
            printf("ret  = %d\n", ret);
            return 10;
        }

        have = ZCHUNK - s->strm.avail_out;
    } while (s->strm.avail_out == 0);
} while (ret != Z_STREAM_END);
inflateEnd(&s->strm);
return s->size;
```

I got always an Z_DATA_ERROR. What I am doing wrong?????

Answer (score 1):

The data is a perfectly valid gzip stream. You have not shown your whole program, so we can't help.